# Pass a variable to an other view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I try to load a view(project_template) in an other view. 
My problem ist, how i can give my $project-variable to the 'project_template'-view which i create in my main-view with "View:make".

Actually i use 
->with($project)
But when I try to use it in my template_view, i get an non-object-error
I also used "compact" what also not worked for me.

In my main-view i can use the $project-variable without problems

View:

```
@foreach($projects as $project)
<tr class="gradeA">
   <td>
   <td>{!! $project->description !!}</td>
   <td>
      {!! View::make('shared.tables.project_template')->with($project)->render() !!}
   </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Project_Template-View:

```
{!! $project->project_name !!}
```

Error-Message

```
ErrorException in 0f9dcdc70fd0be3b50d7a39ad7bc90d7 line 4:
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: laravel? blade can't use View::make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to this:

```
@foreach($projects as $project)
<tr class="gradeA">
   <td>
   <td>{!! $project->description !!}</td>
   <td>
         @include('shared.tables.project_template')
   </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is, that i need to pass a value to the subview (project_template) named $project.

Comment: Just use that variable in your subview and it will be available there. When you include a view like I showed, that variable ($project) will be in the parent view's scope. So just try this and it would work. Nothing else to change

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `@include(viewName, [data])`.

That means, in your case:

`@include('shared.tables.project_template', ['project' => $project])`